# An equal amount of hydrogen gas is dissolved in a 1L vessel and a 2L vessel, both filled with water. Which vessel has higher entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

This question came up in our chemistry class and we could not determine which would have the higher entropy. Clearly, Vessel 2 has a larger volume, but Vessel 1 has a higher concentration of $H_2$. How do we resolve this?

Comment: Why does the concentration matter?

Comment: Please don't use MathJax in the tile. it make the question less searchable

Comment: If a seemingly simple question is hard to answer, then it is likely badly put. ;-) Entropy is an extensive property. The 2l vessel already contains twice the entropy before dissolving hydrogen in it.

Answer (score 2):

Denote by Vessel I the vessel with volume $V$, moles of water $N$, and moles of hydrogen $N'$. Denote by Vessel II the vessel with volume $2V$, moles of water $2N$, and moles of hydrogen $N'$.

Increasing the volume will increase the number of microstates available to the system, and hence also the entropy. Increasing the moles of water will increase the number of microstates available to the system, and hence also the entropy.

Both statements imply that Vessel II has the greater entropy.